# User interaction in Processing

Tags: processing, user-interaction

I have a general question (I know I should present specific code with a problem, but in my case the problem is of a more general nature).

In Processing, let's say I make an ellipse:

```
ellipse(30, 30, 10, 10);
```

Now, is there a way to get the pixels where this ellipse is on the canvas? The reason would be to have a way of creating user interaction with the mouse (for instance). So when someone clicks the mouse over the ellipse, something happens.

I thought of turning everything into objects and use a constructor to somehow store the position of the shape, but this is easier said than done, particularly for more complex shapes. And that is what I am interested in. It's one thing to calculate the position of an ellipse, but what about more complex shapes? Are there any libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [geomerative](http://www.ricardmarxer.com/geomerative/) library. It has a way to check whether the mouse is inside any SVG shape. I can't remember off the top of my head but it works something like you make a shape:

```
myShape = RG.loadShape("shape.svg");
```

and a point:

```
RPoint p = new RPoint(mouseX, mouseY);
```

and the boolean function contains() will tell you if the point is inside the shape:

```
myShape.contains(p);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, will check it out. So it takes only vectors, or other shapes as well?

Comment: Check out the documentation from their website. You have RMesh, RShape, RPolygon, etc. and I believe most of those have a `contains()` function.

Answer (score 3):

It's better to use a mathematical formula than pixel-by-pixel checking of the mouse position (it's much faster, and involves less code).

For a perfect circle, you can calculate the Euclidean distance using Pythagoras' theorem. Assume your circle is centred at position (`circleX`,`circleY`), and has a **radius** (not diameter) of `circleR`. You can check if the mouse is over the circle like this:

```
if(sq(mouseX-circleX)+sq(mouseY-circleY) <= sq(circleR)) {
    // mouse is over circle
} else {
    // mouse is not over circle
}
```

This approach basically imagines a right-angled triangle, where the hypotenuse (the longest side) runs from the centre of the circle to the mouse position. It uses Pythagoras' theorem to calculate the length of that hypotenuse, and if it's less than the circle's radius then the mouse is inside the circle. (It includes a slight optimisation though -- it's comparing squares to avoid doing a square root, as that can be comparatively slow.)

Comment: Ok, that's fine and all for a circle, but what about more complex shapes? Vectors and curves? I have been looking for a library with methods that can do this automatically, but I have yet come across any.

Comment: The same principle can apply to any 2-dimensional shape you like -- you just need to find a mathematical representation. Complex shapes can typically be formed as a combination of several simpler shapes, or by defining a polygon. There are lots of good texts on real-time collision detection which would have relevant formulae.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to my original mathematical answer also occurred to me. If you can afford the memory and processing power of drawing all your UI elements twice then you can get good results by using a secondary buffer.

The principle involves having an off-screen graphics buffer (e.g. using PGraphics). It must be exactly the same size as the main display, and have anti-aliasing disabled. Draw all your interactive UI elements (buttons etc.) to this buffer. However, instead of drawing them the normal way, give each one a unique colour which it uses for fill and stroke (don't add any text or images... just solid colours). For example, one button might be entirely red, and another entirely green. Any other RGB value works, as long as each item has a unique colour. Make sure the background has a unique colour too.

The user never sees that buffer, so don't draw it to the screen (unless you're debugging or something). When you want to detect what item the mouse is over, just lookup the mouse position on that off-screen buffer. Get the pixel colour at that location, and match it to the UI element.

After you've done all that, just go ahead and draw everything to the main display as normal.

It's worth noting that you can cut-down the processing time of this approach a lot if your UI elements never (or rarely) move. You only need to redraw the secondary buffer when something appears/disappears, animates, or changes size/position.